# How can I represent a column vector with Github supported LaTeX?

Tags: mathjax, github-flavored-markdown

I am trying to represent a vector

```
$\begin{bmatrix} X \\ Y \end{bmatrix}$
```

Although this renders correctly in my VS Code, it does not render at all when I push it to Github. Do I have a way of correctly creating a column vector what is supported with Github-flavoured-markdown?

Comment: you could replace whitespaces as `$\begin{bmatrix}X\\Y\end{bmatrix}$`, and and try it should work, but i recommend to read this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32824/show-inline-math-as-if-it-were-display-math-and-vice-versa and https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/issues/573

Comment: @ellhe-blaster Unfortunately with the white spaces removed it still does not work. What I find odd is that what is rendered on Github is `$\begin{bmatrix}X\Y\end{bmatrix}$` i.e. it seems only one backslash is being kept between X and Y if that is a clue.

Comment: @ellhe-blaster I pushed it with four `\\\\` so that it displays two `\` when pushed, unfortunately still did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needed to be nested inside ```math

````
```math
$\begin{bmatrix} X \\ Y \end{bmatrix}$
```
````